# Spring Cloud: How to manage request failure with Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, hystrix, spring-cloud-gateway, resilience4j

I'm working on a micro-service architecture and I'd like to manage all external traffic with an api gateway and monitor the requests failure of specific routes to generate an alert when third-party api (external services) goes down. How I can do that, please ?

Thanks

Comment: zuul does not do any alerting.

Comment: Zuul doesn't do any alerting but we can manage external traffic to handle requests and call alert system, why not ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "manage external traffic to handle requests and call alert system".

Comment: I'd like to check each external request that fails then storing its status in kibana or anything else to generate an alert when I reach a rate limit of failure for example.

Comment: @jonn do you mean upstream when you say "external services"? If yes, then this is not something that Zuul can take care of. The up and down status of upstream services is and should be taken care of by a Circuit Breaker. For instance, Hystrix. Hystrix publishes events which you can then capture and ingest in an ES to achieve what you are trying to achieve.